# Clean URL - removing index.php from URL in CI not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter v.3.0.4 and I'm unable to remove the 'index.php' from URL.

1. I've added the .htaccess file:

   ```
   <ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /project_01/

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
   </ifmodule>
   <ifmodule !mod_rewrite.c="">

   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
   </ifmodule>
   ```
2. In application folder > config.php > I edited the value to:

   ```
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   ```

   And:

   ```
   $config['uri_protocol']= 'REQUEST_URI';
   ```

   And:

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Project_01/';
   ```
3. I checked that my Apache server conf file does not have the pound sign next to the line:

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```

What am I doing wrong? Or what am I not doing?

It worked fine in prior versions of CI, what changed?

Comment: can you give an example URL and what it should be rewritten to?

Comment: instead of the CI default structure "http://localhost/Project_01/index.php/about" I wanna make it a clean URL, without the 'index.php' like so: "http://localhost/Project_01/about"

Comment: The Rewrite seems ok as long as its in /Project_01/.htaccess. what's the problem you're seeing when you request `localhost/Project_01/about` ?

Answer (score 1):

Because your rule is sending the request to the query string, you need to use `QUERY_STRING` for the `uri_protocol`, and not `REQUEST_URI`.

As an alternative, and if you would like to keep `REQUEST URI`, you can change the rule to either one of the following:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

```bash
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I changed the rule to: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  .  And still I get 404 - The requested URL /Project_01/gallery/ was not found on this server.  dont know what am I not doing... all of the code can be downloaded from: https://github.com/Revitalizm/Project_01   .   Please advise.